# Problem with iOS 12 with fullscreen mode on iPad - phishing detection false positive

Tags: ios, security, safari, fullscreen

In iOS 12 Apple appear to have implemented a security feature which detects rapid interaction with the iPad screen when in fullscreen mode and displays a warning message in the centre of the display which reads -

```
'It looks like you are typing while in full screen. Typing is not allowed in full-screen websites. "your-website" may be showing a fake keyboard to trick you into disclosing personal or financial information'
```

The problem for us is that we are currently dragging a Google map and reacting to Google Map events, no keyboard events are fired, and as far as I can tell, nothing can be done to turn this off. Short of writing a letter to Apple explaining that I'm a developer and not a bad actor, I'm not sure how to counter this? Anyone any ideas?

Turning full screen mode off for Safari would probably solve it, but I'd just like to explore if anyone else has any potential solutions.